# How can I change Slickgrid editor button css class (or any dynamically created button)?

Tags: css, button, slickgrid

I am trying to change the editor button (save, cancel) css in Slickgrid. How do I apply a css class to the button item as shown below?

```
<body>
    <div><button>save</button></div>
</body>
```

I tried to bind the cell double click event to this code:

```
$("body button").addClass("custom_button");
```

It was not working because:

1. the event is called before the button is rendered
2. all other < div >< button > items are affected.

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

1. I can't use tag but class for css styling for some reason.
2. If you have not used slickgrid before, this button only appears after you double click grid cell.

Answer (score 0):

Give the button an id.

```
<button id="saveButton">save</button>
```

That way you can call it directly

```
$("saveButton").addClass("custom_button");
```

Comment: How do I add id to this dynamically created button, because it was not in the dom tree until I double click the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style all buttons in the body, you can just use CSS.  Put the style from your `custom_button` class in a CSS selector, put something like this in the `head` of your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body button {
        /* styles from custom_button class go here */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks I was doing that, but I was told to change to use class for some reason.

Comment: How are the buttons getting added to the grid?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, just need to modify slickgrid source code.

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify the slickgrid source. If the buttons are created by a custom formatter then you can add the `custom_button` class in the formatter, if they're part of an editor then you can add the class when the editor creates the button.

Comment: They are part of the longtext editor, which is inside the source code, so the button is created within the source code. What I need to do to add class outside?

Answer (score 0):

just modify slickgrid.editor.js and apply the class.